# How to prevent javascript inside firefox from closing a window/tab?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I am debugging a website using firebug. The website opens a window, performs some operations and than closes it. This causes me to lose all of the firebug net history. Is there any way to prevent javastript from closing the window after its done, except changing the code?

Comment: I had the exact same problem. I ended up adding a breakpoint in the js code at the place that triggered the close so that I could inspect the net history up to that point.

Comment: This makes me extremely angry. How could any browser allow such an action to be performed from a web page?! I want to set things on fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried to use it, but there's a settings in FF which supposedly lets you do what you wish.

Type about:config in the url bar and press enter. After a warning you'll see the list of config options. Search for dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows and set its value to false.

Comment: this does not work on the windows that the script has created. still, this seems like the best option to me

Answer (score 4):

You can rewrite the `open` method, which adds a `beforeunload` event. Have a look at the annotated code + bookmarklet below:

Code:

```
javascript:(function(w){
    var o = w.open;       /* Stores original `window.open` method */
    w.open = function() { /* Catches all window.open calls*/
        var x = o.apply(w, arguments); /* Calls original window.open */
        /* Bind beforeunload event */
        x.addEventListener('beforeunload',function(e){e.preventDefault()},true);
        return x;
    }
})(window);
```

Bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(w){var o=w.open;w.open=function(){var x=o.apply(w,arguments);x.addEventListener('beforeunload',function(e){e.preventDefault()},true);return x;}})(window);
```

Comment: @ArsenZahray Is the website contained in a frame? In that case, replace the `window` at the end of the bookmarklet with, say, `frames[0]` (=the first frame in your document). If the website contains multiple frames, you can loop through all frames, and add this event to it.